# Google Map Geocode API returns only top 6 results...How do I get more?

Tags: api, google-maps

I am using the following uri's to connect to Google Api from a C# class.  I left the address that I am currently having trouble with in it as an example.

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Mt%20Vernon&sensor=false

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Mt%20Vernon,%20IN&sensor=false

The first link only returns what appears to be the top 6 results.  The second link is the result I actually need.   I understand that I can force the user to supply the state, but the requirements that I am under are explicit that only the city need be entered.

I have searched for a way to increase the result set to no avail.  At this point I am looking for any ideas short of switching to some other services (which I am not opposed to if google, indeed has this short coming).

Thanks for whatever help you might be able to provide.

Comment: I have a suggestion that will only help if you're limiting the searches to only one state, say Indiana. Behind the scenes, just add " Indiana - United States" to the user-supplied text. It doesn't seem to hurt if the user does enter the state name. I just don't see any way for Google Maps to guess which state the user means. I'm curious if there's a real answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Geocoding ambiguous addresses with google maps API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33505558/geocoding-ambiguous-addresses-with-google-maps-api)

Answer (score 0):

If you include USA in your search parameter,  the Mt. Vernon result from Indiana is included:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Mt%20Vernon,USA&sensor=false
```

Not sure if it helps any, since it may have a different behavior with a different query,  but it does satisfy the original issue.

Comment: it does help this particular situation with that specific city.  But to further complicate the issue, the addresses that might be searched include Canada and or Mexico.  So the real query: is there a way to tell Google map api to change the max result set from 6 to some other arbitrary number.