# Google geocoding api only returning 1 result

Tags: google-geocoding-api

I only seem able to get 1 result for this link:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=high%20street&region=gb

Seeing as there are hundreds of "high street"s in the UK I would expect this to return many more than 1, can anyone help, I am sure this used to work.

Comment: In this question the example is very similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10000857/google-map-geocode-api-returns-only-top-6-results-how-do-i-get-more You can modify the query to look like yours (json instead of xml) and get more than one results back. So asking for Mt%20Vernon gives more than one result, asking for a high%20street does not. I guess it's very hard to predict, what Google is returning for any given query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Geocoding ambiguous addresses with google maps API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33505558/geocoding-ambiguous-addresses-with-google-maps-api)